# Populate Db values in my textbox based on my dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This is my Dropdown Box Code:-

```
<select name="cat" id="cat" onchange="get_data(this.value)" required>
  <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
  <option value="team1">team1</option>
  <option value="team2">team2</option>
  <option value="IT">IT</option>
  <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
</select>
```

My textbox code following below:-

```
<input placeholder="Phone Number" name="phoneNumber" type="text" required>
```

JavaScript code:-

```
function get_data(value){
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajaxdropdown.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "HTML",
        async: false,
        data: {value: value}

     });
 }
    </script>
```

**ajaxdropdown.php**

```
<?php
include('session.php');
$cat = (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cat'));

$sql = mysql_query("select Mobile from user_content where Category='" . $cat . "'") or die(mysql_error());
$value_frank = mysql_fetch_row($sql);
$val_fra = $value_frank;

echo $val_fra;// here no need to use sessions at all.

      ?>
```

My sample DB table:-

```
 -------------------------
| ID  | Category | Mobile |
 -------------------------
| 001 | team1    | 962222 |
| 002 | team2    | 962562 |
| 003 | team2    | 962334 |
 -------------------------
```

So I want to change textbox value based on my drop-down selection.

For example when I select my dropdown value "team2" then it will check DB and display matching Moblie Field records on my textbox one by one separated by the comma.

Drop down Value Selection: team2
Textbox value: 962562,962334

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you have tried? You can achieve by ajax call on change of dropdown value.

Comment: you can used onchange method for dropdown field ,then send selected category to server using ajax and compare to the table with category and return mobile number then set  that mobile to textbox using jquery.

Comment: hi, now I provided my full code. please review my code once again and suggest me if any changes needed.

Comment: what is the issue you are facing

Comment: I think totally not working. when I select drop-down options, textbox cannot be filled